# What SEC Forms Show Stock Buy Backs and Government Bail out money

Tags: sec

I've been randomly searching forms and I pulled up this https://www.sec.gov/forms. However, I'm financially illiterate to the point that I don't know what terminology I'm looking for.

I've seen that FED buy backs tend to happen in the form of issued warrants or bonds, which kind of looks like 424B2 and FW1 Forms, but I haven't been able to identify if the fed's are the ones buying these bonds as a means to "bail them out".

I'm also at a complete loss as to figure out how much a company is buying it's own shares up. SG 13G and 13 F seemed promising, but I haven't been able to match a google search with of company buy back with the actual sec form that provided that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to find stock repurchase details is probably to check the 10-K of the company in question. Repurchase will be in a section named "Consolidated Statement of Changes in Shareholders' Equity" or equivalent. Look for a line item "Common Stock Repurchased".

Use [Edgar](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) on the SEC site To find and retrieve the 10-K.

Concerning the financial crisis government bail out money (TARP and the Fannie & Freddie buyouts), ProPublica already tracks this. See their [online bailout tracker](https://projects.propublica.org/bailout/). So for example, as of today the US has made $4.5B off of entity #5 Bank of America but is down 11.3B from entity #4 General Motors (US net made money off the "bailout").

EDIT: you can get more TARP data straight from the Treasury Department's web site. They have a [TARP tracker](https://www.treasury.gov/initiatives/financial-stability/reports/Pages/TARP-Tracker.aspx#All) and other resources.

Comment: I saw the propublica and was wondering how they track that information. I thought that info could be seen in the sec filings. I only prefer that as a data source because I already parse SEC documentation.

Comment: Original source for most things TARP is the Treasury Department. They have a TARP Tracker page and more under https://www.treasury.gov/initiatives/financial-stability/Pages/default.aspx.